# Toolbar layout with Qt Designer

Tags: qt, layout, qt-designer, qtoolbar

I use the Qt Designer to design `.ui` files and compile them in my VS-Project.
We have a Toolbar class, derived from QToolbar.

Class initialization looks like this.

```
MyToolBar::ToolBar(QWidget* qWidgetParent) :
    ToolBar(qWidgetParent),
    mUiToolBar(new Ui::MyToolBar())
    {
        mUiToolBar->setupUi(this);
        //...
     }
```

Everything works fine for fixed positions and sizes. But if I start using a layout for automatic formating everything is broken. In this case everything is on the topleft position.

Any Idea whats happen in this case? What is the correct way to use layouts in a QToolbar?

edit: i have copied the code from my project. In this MyToolBar is derived by ToolBar, a class for managing the same functionality. ToolBar is derived by QToolBar.

Comment: Can you show how you are adding widgets to the `MyToolBar`? I assume `MyToolbar` is inherited from `QToolBar`, not from `Toolbar`?

Comment: This was a mistake from copy code. MyToolBar is dervied by ToolBar by QToolBar. I edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a ToolBar is meant to have a Layout. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Seeing everything in the topleft position that should be in a Layout is a sign that either those child Widgets were not added to the Layout (using `QLayout::addWidget(...)`) or that the Layout was not added to the parent Widget (your ToolBar, using `QWidget::setLayout(...)`).

Also, you probably meant to call `QToolBar(qWidgetParent),` in stead of `ToolBar(qWidgetParent),`.

Comment: I think the best is to remove the layout. I am not able to find a good Widget <-> Layout dependency.

Comment: @norca Then add the Widgets to your ToolBar using the QToolBar::addWidget(...) function. But normally a QToolBar should only have QActions, which you can add with QToolBar::addAction(...).

Comment: My toolbar has buttons and checkboxes, we aimed to have everything scaleable with layout.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to call `QToolBar::addWidget()`, but you are setting parent of the widgets to the `QToolBar` widget.

This will create all widgets at (0,0) position (relative to the parent), but it will not layout them as you are expecting to.